# routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have two identically controllers routed in the same way :

> ```
> resources :profile
> resources :friends
> ```

here are the controllers

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController



def index
@text = "profile"
end
def show
end
def new 
end
def create
end
def edit
end
def update
end
def destroy
end

end





class FriendsController < ApplicationController


def index
@text = "friends"
end
def show

end
def new 
end
def create
end
def edit
end
def update
end
def destroy
end

end
```

but when i want to define a menu in the view layout , a problem occurs for the profile controller but not also for the friends controller . Here is the code that generates the error :

```
<ul id="menu">

<li>
<%= link_to "Friends",friends_path %>
</li>
<li>
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path %>
</li>


</ul>
```

and the error is :

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profile"}
```

Why is this happening if the controllers and views are identical ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to the fact that you've given your Profile controller a singular name and route.  You can run `rake routes` to find out what the route helpers are named.  Look for `GET /profile`, it might be something like `index_profile_path` or `profile_index_path`

Edit: more specifically, the error is because it's expecting by default for `profile_path` to be the helper for showing a certain instance, e.g. `profile_path(@profile)`

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<%= link_to "Profile", profiles_path %>
```

The difference is in the variable name profile **s** _path. As the path to the index url should be in plural.

You can also see all the routes if your application by running `rake routes` - it's a live saver to debug routes problems.

Comment: no , that is not it .. i've tried it earlier and i've tried it now . i get the error : undefined local variable or method `profiles_path' for #<#<Class:0xa095f74>:0xa0944bc> so i think that this is not the problem